# change name of property in a list to list nested json using JOLT

Tags: java, arrays, json, transformation, jolt

I am news to jolt json transformation. So looking for help in transforming nested json having list of values to nested json with list as following.

**Input json**

```json
{
  "userData": [
    {
      "userId": "1",
      "age": "20",
      "firstName": "firstname1",
      "lastname": "lastname1",
      "zipCode": "zipcode1",
      "street": "street1",
      "city": "city1",
      "country": "country",
      "gender": "gender1",
      "grade": "grade1",
      "birthday": "birthday1"
    },
    {
      "userId": "2",
      "age": "25",
      "firstName": "firstname2",
      "lastname": "lastname2",
      "zipCode": "zipcode2",
      "street": "street2",
      "city": "city2",
      "country": "country2",
      "gender": "gender2",
      "grade": "grade2",
      "birthday": "birthday2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Specification**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userData": {
        "*": {
          "userId": "data.[&1].ID",
          "*": "data.[&1].&",
          "zipCode": {
            "#custom-field1": "adr_&1.property",
            "@": "adr_&.value"
          },
          "street": {
            "#custom-field2": "adr_&1.property",
            "@": "adr_&.value"
          },
          "city": {
            "#custom-field3": "adr_&1.property",
            "@": "adr_&.value"
          },
          "country": {
            "#custom-field4": "adr_&1.property",
            "@": "adr_&.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "data" : [ {
    "ID" : "1",
    "age" : "20",
    "firstName" : "firstname1",
    "lastname" : "lastname1",
    "gender" : "gender1",
    "grade" : "grade1",
    "birthday" : "birthday1"
  }, {
    "ID" : "2",
    "age" : "25",
    "firstName" : "firstname2",
    "lastname" : "lastname2",
    "gender" : "gender2",
    "grade" : "grade2",
    "birthday" : "birthday2"
  } ],
  "adr_zipCode" : {
    "property" : [ "custom-field1", "custom-field1" ],
    "value" : [ "zipcode1", "zipcode2" ]
  },
  "adr_street" : {
    "property" : [ "custom-field2", "custom-field2" ],
    "value" : [ "street1", "street2" ]
  },
  "adr_city" : {
    "property" : [ "custom-field3", "custom-field3" ],
    "value" : [ "city1", "city2" ]
  },
  "adr_country" : {
    "property" : [ "custom-field4", "custom-field4" ],
    "value" : [ "country", "country2" ]
  }
}
```

**Expected json**

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "age": "20",
      "firstName": "firstname1",
      "lastname": "lastname1",
      "gender": "gender1",
      "grade": "grade1",
      "birthday": "birthday1",
      "address": [
        {
          "property": "custom-field1",
          "value": "zipcode1"
        },
        {
          "property": "custom-field2",
          "value": "street1"
        },
        {
          "property": "custom-field3",
          "value": "city1"
        },
        {
          "property": "custom-field4",
          "value": "country"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "age": "25",
      "firstName": "firstname2",
      "lastname": "lastname2",
      "gender": "gender2",
      "grade": "grade2",
      "birthday": "birthday2",
      "address": [
        {
          "property": "custom-field1",
          "value": "zipcode2"
        },
        {
          "property": "custom-field2",
          "value": "street2"
        },
        {
          "property": "custom-field3",
          "value": "city2"
        },
        {
          "property": "custom-field4",
          "value": "country2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use individual `value` arrays of their indexes to be used within the upcoming specs with a tricky zeroth member which will be removed later, after been used such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "userData": {
        "*": {
          "userId": "data[&1].ID",
          "@(0,age)": "data[&1].age", //multiplexed this attribute in order to make it the zeroth index, which will be removed within the upcoming specs, for the "address" array at the same time, as indexing starts from zero ...
          "*": "data[&1].&",
          "a*|z*|s*|c*": {//separating "zipCode", "street", "city", "country" attributes from the others while using "a*" for "age" is tricky, temporarily
            "@": "data[&2].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].&",
          "value": {
            "*": {
              "#property": "&4[&3].address[&1].custom-field&1",
              "@(2,value[&])": "&4[&3].address[&1].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // the attributes are written individually to keep the desired sorting
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "ID": "&2[&1].&",
          "age": "&2[&1].&",
          "firstName": "&2[&1].&",
          "lastname": "&2[&1].&",
          "gender": "&2[&1].&",
          "grade": "&2[&1].&",
          "birthday": "&2[&1].&",
          "address": {
            "0": "&4[&3].&2[&1]",
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "$": "&5[&4].&3[&2].@(0)" // key-value pairs are exchanged for this attribute
              },
              "value": "&4[&3].&2[&1].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of null components of the array
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I have got more simple and readable solution for the same

Comment: Hi @PrasadSDeshpande , yes that solution is possible, and is similar to the already presented one within the question, but excuse me, smells a bit like hard-coding, and not preferable for programming's sake. Since you might have ten attributes rather than four, and would need to copy-paste for all those for that case.

Comment: I agree with you

Comment: It seems JOLT operations are chain of operation and each operation creates intermediate json, so in first operation you are shifting all desired property values to value=[] array, then rearranging them to desired format. Is there any chance of getting sequence of values to be changed? 

What if some elements from input array does not contains the property which we want to rearrange in output json?

Comment: Hi @PrasadSDeshpande , I think it would be better to speak concrete examples which contain such cases. So, can you reproduce the desired scenario within a new question, I'll be concerning with it when I'm available.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```json
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "userData": {
                "*": {
                    "userId": "data.[&1].ID",
                    "*": "data.[&1].&",
                    "zipCode": {
                        "#custom-field1": "data[#3].address[#2].property",
                        "@": "data[#3].address[#2].value"
                    },
                    "street": {
                        "#custom-field2": "data[#3].address[#2].property",
                        "@": "data[#3].address[#2].value"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "#custom-field3": "data[#3].address[#2].property",
                        "@": "data[#3].address[#2].value"
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "#custom-field4": "data[#3].address[#2].property",
                        "@": "data[#3].address[#2].value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { // get rid of null components of the array
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson* to do the same job by shorter transformation statement.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"userData\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"userId\": \"1\"," +
    "      \"age\": \"20\"," +
    "      \"firstName\": \"firstname1\"," +
    "      \"lastname\": \"lastname1\"," +
    "      \"zipCode\": \"zipcode1\"," +
    "      \"street\": \"street1\"," +
    "      \"city\": \"city1\"," +
    "      \"country\": \"country\"," +
    "      \"gender\": \"gender1\"," +
    "      \"grade\": \"grade1\"," +
    "      \"birthday\": \"birthday1\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"userId\": \"2\"," +
    "      \"age\": \"25\"," +
    "      \"firstName\": \"firstname2\"," +
    "      \"lastname\": \"lastname2\"," +
    "      \"zipCode\": \"zipcode2\"," +
    "      \"street\": \"street2\"," +
    "      \"city\": \"city2\"," +
    "      \"country\": \"country2\"," +
    "      \"gender\": \"gender2\"," +
    "      \"grade\": \"grade2\"," +
    "      \"birthday\": \"birthday2\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation**

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "map(data:userData" +
    "      .field(ID:userId, userId:," +
    "             zipCode:, street:, city:, country:," +
    "             address:collect(" +
    "               map(property:'customer-field1',value:zipCode)," +
    "               map(property:'customer-field2',value:street)," +
    "               map(property:'customer-field3',value:city)," +
    "               map(property:'customer-field4',value:country))))");
System.out.print(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "data" : [ {
    "age" : "20",
    "firstName" : "firstname1",
    "lastname" : "lastname1",
    "gender" : "gender1",
    "grade" : "grade1",
    "birthday" : "birthday1",
    "ID" : "1",
    "address" : [ {
      "property" : "customer-field1",
      "value" : "zipcode1"
    }, {
      "property" : "customer-field2",
      "value" : "street1"
    }, {
      "property" : "customer-field3",
      "value" : "city1"
    }, {
      "property" : "customer-field4",
      "value" : "country"
    } ]
  }, {
    "age" : "25",
    "firstName" : "firstname2",
    "lastname" : "lastname2",
    "gender" : "gender2",
    "grade" : "grade2",
    "birthday" : "birthday2",
    "ID" : "2",
    "address" : [ {
      "property" : "customer-field1",
      "value" : "zipcode2"
    }, {
      "property" : "customer-field2",
      "value" : "street2"
    }, {
      "property" : "customer-field3",
      "value" : "city2"
    }, {
      "property" : "customer-field4",
      "value" : "country2"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```